# Calling WCF using Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I have tried all the options and referred many websites to solve this requirement and failed to succeed. I don't know what to do now. Can you please help me with this?

I have created WCF service in one domain. and calling that WCF from other domain.

For that, I have created proxy service and attached the reference too. But unfortunately getting 404 not found error. Dont know what to do to get rid of this.

This is my WCF service:

```
public class WCFService : IWCFService
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return "The count is" + value.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}
```

By using jQuery Ajax, I am trying to use WCF from another domain project.

This is the WCF client application with the jQuery ajax call:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;

function CallMyService() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: 'http://localhost:58134/WCFService.svc/GetData',
        url: 'WCFService.svc/GetData',
        data: '{"Count": "' + counter + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json", // content type sent to server
        success: ServiceSucceeded,
        error: ServiceFailed
    });
}

// ---- WCF Service call backs -----
function ServiceFailed(result) {
    Log('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '  ' + result.statusText);
}

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    var resultObject = result.MyFunctionResult;
    Log("Success: " + resultObject);
}

// ---- Log ------
// utility function to output messages
function Log(msg) {
    $("#Label1").append(msg + "<br />");
}
</script>
```

This is the markup for UI part:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Execute" onclick="CallMyService();"/>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
```

I have created a proxy class for this too, In local WCF is working fine. But I am trying to access this from Client application it throwing an error like "404 not Found".

Calling above method through `Onclick()` event. What and all options I can make here to get the successful WCF call from cross domains.

Do I need to change any settings in `web.config` file?

I am new to these concepts. So please try to help me on this. I didn't get any information from any website to achieve this.

Could you please try to help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your service config? Can you post it please?

Comment: What is the full address of the service you are calling from the Ajax post? (WCFService.svc\GetData) is it http://localhost:58134/WCFService.svc/GetData?

Comment: The ajax code you have works. the url needs to be the full address to the service i.e. 'http://localhost:58134/WCFService.svc/GetData' or whatever it is. Make sure your service is running by pulling up the url in a browser. Also, if your contract and service are not config'd for JSON, then you will have that to deal with too.